# How to speed up Django's admin pages with PostgreSQL count estimates?

Tags: django, performance, postgresql, admin, paginator

It's quite known that Django's admin list views are getting rather slow when the database tables have lots of rows. That's because the Django paginator uses by default a (slow) PostgreSQL `COUNT` query.

As estimate would be fine for us and it's much faster, e.g.:
`SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = "my_table_name"`

There is snippet available to fix this issue, but it's unclear to me how to actually use it:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2593/

Also, the snippet is not supposed to work on filtered results. That's because the estimate count as shown above doesn't work here. Is there another way to speed up filtered list views in Django admin pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use it by overriding the [ModelAdmin.paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.paginator)

> The paginator class to be used for pagination. By default,
>   django.core.paginator.Paginator is used. If the custom paginator class
>   doesn’t have the same constructor interface as
>   django.core.paginator.Paginator, you will also need to provide an
>   implementation for ModelAdmin.get_paginator().

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    paginator = CachingPaginator
```

Bonus feature: I have improved on that snippet to create one that works with and without filters: https://gist.github.com/e4c5/6852723 it gets the count from rel_tuples when possible but when a filter is used the count is saved to the cache.

**Update 1:**
The problem with the original snippet reffered to in your answer is due to this change announced in the 1.6 release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.6/#get-query-set-and-similar-methods-renamed-to-get-queryset

It's a trivial fix.

**update 2**
My improvement to the original snippet has been made some what obsolete by the _count propert being renamed to count and also it being decorated as a [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property)

Comment: I see how to use it; but neither script seems to be working with Django 1.10. Yours returns the error `CachingPaginator object has no attribute '_count'` - the original script returns `'LargeTableChangeList' object has no attribute 'query_set'` - any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, still not working. Renamed `_count` to `count`. Now I'm getting the error `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` for the line `if self.count is None:` - in both, yours and the other snippet.

Comment: I think we are now far from the original scope of the question, which was about how to use that snippet and we have I think covered that more than adequately here. Please post a new question saying you are using this snippet (include the code in the question itself) along with the error trace

Comment: please do share link when you post the new question.

Comment: Here's the link to the new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851915/faster-django-admin-paginator-cannot-get-this-django-snippet-to-work Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is an option to choose the desired behaviour since Django 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.show_full_result_count

Example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    show_full_result_count = False
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)